# What are the parameters for AlertDialog.Builder()?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I am working on creating my first test app using Android Studio and Kotlin.
Also, should I just not use Kotlin when developing apps? I was told to use Kotlin..
Anyways back to my problem.

I wanted to know what the parameters were for `AlertDialog.Builder(this)`
I know it's supposed to be `this` or `this@mainactivity` but I don't know what the parameter is.
There is no intellisense and I couldnt find any documents.

Comment: @MikeM. It must be noted that there are other version of AlertDialog.Builder, which resides in `support.v7`. Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: @TheStrikeBone Still the same parameter type.

Comment: "Also, should I just not use Kotlin when developing apps? I was told to use Kotlin" By all means use Kotlin to develop Android apps, it's awesome! (No sarcasm)

Answer (score -1):

How about a custom Alert Dialog that yes it is boiler plate code but oh the style!

You need this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDI"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/caution" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDAT"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Delete Note"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDAC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Do You Want to DELETE this Note"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnYES"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:background="@color/color_Transparent"
    android:text="DELETE"
    android:textColor="@color/color_deepBlue"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNO"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:background="@color/color_Transparent"
    android:text="CANCEL"
    android:textColor="@color/color_deepBlue"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

here is the button that calls the view

```
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener{
        if(etPerson.text.toString().equals("")){
            message("No Match Found")
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        doCustom()

    }
```

And now doCustom IT is a little funky to call the other function

```
    fun doCustom() {
 /* This method uses the custom_dialog.xml file created for greater control over
the styling of the Custom Alert Dialog for various screen sizes and to be
able to set the text size of the dialog message text
*/

 val makeDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null)
 val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(makeDialog)
 val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

 val btnYES = makeDialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnYES)
 val btnNO = makeDialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnNO)
 mAlertDialog.setCancelable(false)

 btnYES.setOnClickListener {
     removePerson()
     mAlertDialog.dismiss()
 }

 btnNO.setOnClickListener {
     message("Record NOT Deleted")
     etPerson.setText("")
     Timer().schedule(800){
         thisACTIVITY()
     }
     mAlertDialog.dismiss()
 }
 mAlertDialog.show()
}

private fun removePerson() {

    val dbHandler = DBHelper(this)

    val result = dbHandler.deletePerson(etPerson.text.toString())

    if (result) {
        etPerson.setText("")
        message("Record Removed")
        Timer().schedule(1000){
            thisACTIVITY()
        }
    }else{
        etPerson.setText("NO MATCH -> click View Person List")
        btnViewList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        btnEdit.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        btnDelete.visibility =View.INVISIBLE
        btnAdd.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        message("NO Match Found")
    }
}
```